# How to create a case insensitive Regexp from a non-case insensitive Regexp?

Tags: ruby, regex

Given a hash of regular expressions defined with forward slashes (`'/'`) , I'd like to test whether a string matches any of them.

My match should be case insensitive, but I don't want to explicitly make use of the [`i` flag](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html) at the end of the regexps in my hash.

```
str="ENTITY foo is END"

kw={
 ent: /entity/,
 end: /end/
}

kw.each do |kw_id,rex|
  p rex.match(str)
end
```

This fails because `rex` are not made case insensitive (of course just adding a `'i'` at the end of my regexp would do the trick, but this is not what I want).

So I modified my code like this, in order to compose a new regexp :

```
kw.each do |kw_id,rex|
  rexi=Regexp.new(rex.to_s,true)
  p rexi.match(str)
end
```

But again, this cannot recognize any part of the string.

So how do I create a *case insensitive* Regexp from a *non-case insensitive* Regexp?

Comment: If adding `i` to the end of the pattern does the trick, then what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: a generic lexer, where I can propose an option for case insensitivity

Comment: Why not just use the `i` option when the user wants to use the lexer without case-sensitivity? Any other solution is reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add the case-insensitive "ignore case" option on the fly:

```
original = /abc/
insensitive = Regexp.new(
                original.source, 
                original.options | Regexp::IGNORECASE)
```

To make the match case-insensitive without using the "ignore case" option, a possible solution is to create a regexp that matches uppercase letters and lowercase letter like this:

```
original = /abc/ 
insensitive = /[Aa][Bb][Cc]/
```

If your original regexps are all letters as in your examples, you can automate like this:

```
original = /abc/
insensitive = Regexp.new(
                original.source.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]/){ "[#{$&.upcase}#$&]" })
```

If your original regexps are more than just letters, then you'll need a more sophisticated automation. For example, if your original regexps make use of braces, character classes, named captures, etc. then you'll need code that take these into account. (Thanks to hobbs in the comments for emphasizing this)

Comment: Why try to parse `inspect` when we have [`Regexp#source`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Regexp.html#method-i-source)?